# Enable/disable usage of specified [JsonProperty] name

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way how to programmatically enable/disable usage of property name specified by `[JsonProperty]`?

When I serialize:

```
public class Dto
{
    [JsonProperty("l")]
    public string LooooooooooooongName { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to see an output "in debug":

```
{
    "LooooooooooooongName":"Data"
}
```

And "in release":

```
{
    "l":"Data"
}
```

Comment: You mean for your whole program, in every classes at once?

Comment: Yes, I have several tens of DTOs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a resolver to handle the job.

```
public class NoJsonPropertyNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {

        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.PropertyName = property.UnderlyingName;
        return property;
    }
}
```

and somewhere in your startup code

```
#if DEBUG
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
                ContractResolver = new NoJsonPropertyNameContractResolver()
        };
#endif
```

You now have inconsistent behaviour between your Debug and Release build (but why?).

Comment: Thanks, The reason is simply that I want to make sure the output is as small as possible (and short property names make a significant difference in output length). While in development I would like to benefit from the full names for readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [C# preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx):

```
public class Dto
{
#if !DEBUG
    [JsonProperty("l")]
#endif    
    public string LooooooooooooongName { get; set; }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Ок, maybe this is not very convenient if you must do it around the whole application. Another more convenient approach could be to implement custom `ContractResolver` and place this preprocessor directive only in one place.

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

#if DEBUG
        if(prop != null)
        {
            // If in debug mode -> return PropertyName value to the initial member name. 
            prop.PropertyName = member.Name;
        }
#endif

        return prop;
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObj, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(),
});
```

**Note**: you can implement wrapper around JsonConverter or use default json serializer settings, so you wont need to specify the contract resolver every time.

Comment: True, but pain in the ass

Comment: Thanks for your reply but @tia offered this solution first. BTW His solution is also better considering it changes the behavior in DEBUG mode only.